# How can I insert/update external table while do a node_save

Tags: drupal-7, node-save

I need to save two details about my `node` but I don't want to do so in the traditional way (**I don't want to use the field_data tables**). I would like to create a new table with the `nid as foreign key` and the two columns with the details.

So is there any way to insert into this custom table while we are calling `node_save` functionality? Also is it possible to call these details while we call `node_load` functionality?

Comment: see [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) and [hook_node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7.x) try add you functionality to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use drupal hook for custom table update or insert new row like

```
function hook_insert($node) {
     db_insert('mytable')
        ->fields(array(
        'nid' => $node->nid,
        'extra' => $node->extra,
      ))->execute();

    $num_updated = db_update('node') // Table name no longer needs {}
      ->fields(array(
        'uid' => 5,
        'status' => 1,
      ))
      ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
      ->execute();
  }
```